# Why isn't my text-align: center; working properly?

Tags: html, css

Why isn't my `text-align: center;` working? The `text` and the `span` are supposed to be in the center of the image, (I'm kind of new at this, please understand).

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="image">
    <div id="imageContainer">
        <span><h1>Responsive Web</h1></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS looks like this:

```
   #imageContainer h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    } 
    #imageContainer span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.5em 0.2em;
    border: white solid 10px;
   }
```

I don't understand why it isn't working, my `H1` tag isn't listening to my `text-align: center;` and neither is my `span`. This might be a newbie question, (lol) but this confuses me a lot, help please!

Comment: For good HTML Markup, you need to put the span inside the `<h1>`and not the inverse

Comment: Use display:block property for the #imageContainer span this div which will make center

Answer (score 0):

Remove the display property

```
#imageContainer span {

padding: 0.5em 0.2em;
border: white solid 10px;
}
```

Comment: But then my span isn't around my H1, it goes like cut in half and into the left side where I kind of can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Or put the width: 100% on

```
#imageContainer span {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's supposed to look like this: https://github.com/DevTips/Artists-Theme/blob/gh-pages/assets/img/the_design.jpg

Comment: so whats the problem with putting width 100% on span element ? When the span is inline-block it will not shrink 100% and if its not 100% u cant center the text

Comment: The problem is that the span is supposed to surround the H1, now the span stretches out the entire background.

Comment: I see, then put this: #imageContainer{text-align:center}

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `display: inline-block;` to your `span`, the `span` is only as width as its content. You will have to set its `width` to `100%` to get it working, or remove the `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: If I set the width to 100% it's working, but the span stretches out the entire background, and when I remove the display: inline-block; the span goes to a hard left where I almost can't see it, it's supposed to look like the Artist Theme on this URL: https://github.com/DevTips/Artists-Theme/blob/gh-pages/assets/img/the_design.jpg

Comment: This may happen because the `span`s parent's position is not relative, or it has no fixed width. How is your #imageContainer styled? `width: 100%` sets the width to 100% of its parent.

Comment: My #imageContainer is styled as following: #imageContainer {
 height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url(/Users/James/Desktop/mountain4k.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
}

Comment: Is the #imageContainer's width as it should be? Try adding `position: relative` to your #imageContainer to be sure that the `span`s width can be applied to its parent with `width: 100%`.

Comment: Nothing happens when I write position: relative to my #imageContainer.

Comment: Use display:block for #imageContainer span this div. Then it will make the text center.

Answer (score 0):

try:

> `#imageContainer{   text-align: center; }`

and the rest (span and h1)

> `display: inline-block;` **or** `display: inline;`